# Validation behavior is not doing as expected

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, validationrule

Situation :

When you click on new product a popup screen show ups :

[image]

As you can see the button "Opslagen" is disabled, that is good because "Productnaam" is mandatory.

Now If I start typing the button "Opslagen" is enabled, so far thats ok.

[image]

But when I remove tekst a message in red shows that this field is mandatory, but the button won't disable anymore :

[image]

When I type something again the red text dissapears again. But the button behavior is not working as expected.

The XAML :

```
<TextBox Width="200"
         Height="30"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="ProductName" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validators:EmptyValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" ValidationStep="RawProposedValue" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Placeholder for the TextBox itself -->
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
</TextBox>
```

The EmptyValidationRule class :

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
    {
        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }

    return new ValidationResult(false, "Dit veld is verplicht.");
}
```

And finally the IsSaveButtonDisabled property in the ViewModel :

```
public bool IsSaveButtonEnabled
{
    get
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_productName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_productName))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }    
}
```

I really have no idea. It must be the combination of the ValidationRule and the check if the property ProductName is empty.

Edit, button code :

```
<Button Content="Opslagen"
        IsEnabled="{Binding IsSaveButtonEnabled}"
        Background="Bisque"
        Width="120"
        Height="30"
        Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
```

ProductName property :

```
private string _productName;
public string ProductName
{
    get => _productName;
    set
    {
        _productName = value;

        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ProductName));
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsSaveButtonEnabled));
    }
}
```

The Save command is like this :

```
SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveProduct);
```

And SaveProduct is just a method that saves the product. This stuff is working.

Comment: How is the `Button` enabled or disabled? Are you using a command or how are you disabling it?

Comment: @mm8 The Buttons has the property IsEnabled="{Binding IsSaveButtonEnabled}"

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk thats not the issue.

Comment: @user7849697 Where is implementation of your button? You say, that problem is with your button, but only gave implementation of textbox.

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk updated with the button code.

Comment: @user7849697 Still not enough info. Who how where and when updates _productName, how do you implement SaveCommand

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk added more info.

Comment: When I set a brakepoint in the property IsSaveButtonEnabled it doesn't reach it when the field is empty again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `ValidationStep` property to `UpdatedValue` to run the `ValidationRule` after the source property has been set:

```
<validators:EmptyValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"
                                ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
```

Then the `PropertyChanged` event for the `IsSaveButtonEnabled` property should be invoked and the `Button` should be disabled even if the validation rule fails.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Hmm changed it back and it also worked strange.